# Enter key behavior in wx.grid

Tags: grid, wxpython, enter

Googling a lot without any results... The default behavior of the grid while pressing the enter key is moving cursor down. But I have to make the cell editor opened in the current cell. I can easily hook key event, but how can I open the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import wx
import wx.grid

class MyGrid(wx.grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.CreateGrid(8, 3)

        self.editor = wx.grid.GridCellChoiceEditor(["One", "Two", "Three"])
        self.SetCellEditor(1, 1, self.editor)
        self.SetCellValue(1, 0, "And here.")
        self.SetCellValue(1, 1, "Try here.")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnEnter)


    def OnEnter(self, e):
        if e.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_RETURN or e.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_NUMPAD_ENTER:
            self.EnableCellEditControl()
        else:
            e.Skip()


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid = MyGrid(self)
        self.Show()



app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```